# Making my Artificial Intelligence visuals that react with sound change

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

So basically I have created an A.I assistant and was wondering if anyone had suggestions on how to make visuals that react with the sound?

Comment: So what kind of visualization are you trying to create? Is it going to be a spectrum analyzer like [This](http://www.pas-products.com/images/programs/24-Octave-Spectrum-Analyzer.gif)?

Comment: Yes like a wave form . But with a bit complex visalization like this (http://ak2.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/2181202/thumb/4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can just measure the loudness of the voice command spoken in mDb. You can then process these numbers to change the UI. 
Like , higher the loudness makes the bar longer. Let me know which speech to text engine are you using so that I can provide further help.